# T-SQL create time windows (from/to) with alternating values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, gaps-and-islands

I need to transform rows on a monthly basis to rows with a time window based on alternating values. I have already tried various versions of partition, dense_rank and joins with row_number on row_number-1 but I somehow cannot get to the right result.

Here's my data:

| month_ID | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 202211 | 10 |
| 202212 | 10 |
| 202301 | 10 |
| 202302 | 12 |
| 202303 | 12 |
| 202304 | 10 |
| 202305 | 10 |
| 202306 | 12 |
| 202307 | 12 |

Here's what I want my output to be:

| From | To | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 202211 | 202301 | 10 |
| 202302 | 202303 | 12 |
| 202304 | 202305 | 10 |
| 202306 | 202307 | 12 |

The time frames can differ.

Comment: *"I have already tried various versions of partition"* Include those attempts in your question, so that we can see what it is you've tried, and help you correct it so it works.

Comment: Also, this looks like a gaps and island issue; a search of this methodology should give you a wealth of resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, this is a gaps and island problem. One method is to use a couple of `ROW_NUMBER`s to create the groups, and then you can get the `MIN` and `MAX` for each group:

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT MonthID,
           [Value],
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MonthID ASC) - 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Value] ORDER BY MonthID ASC) AS Grp
    FROM (VALUES(202211,10),
                (202212,10),
                (202301,10),
                (202302,12),
                (202303,12),
                (202304,10),
                (202305,10),
                (202306,12),
                (202307,12))V(MonthID, [Value]))
SELECT MIN(MonthID) AS [From],
       MAX(MonthID) AS [To],
       [Value]
FROM CTE
GROUP BY Grp,
         [Value]
ORDER BY [From];
```

Comment: Thank you so much. To me the buzzword "gaps and island problem" is new, so that was already a great hint!
Now, I have tried to apply your code, however now I just get a single row for each monthID:

From | To | Value
202211 | 202211 | 10
202212 | 202212 | 10
and so on..

Comment: I don't follow what you mean by *"I just get a single row for each monthID"*, @Curti7 . The answer, above, returns the results you want: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e5f7708fa444996cdeb9fead38b3efe5)

Comment: My fault, I missinterpreted the "minus" (-) - now it works perfectly. Thank you very much :-)